# Independence of events vs dependence

Tags: probability, independence

I am a bit confused over a problem that is as follows:

A coin is tossed three times. Consider the following events 
A: Heads on the first toss.
B: Tails on the second.
C: Heads on the third toss.
D: All three outcomes the same (HHH or TTT). E: Exactly one head turns up.

(a) Which of the following pairs of these events are independent?

(1) A, B

(2) A, D

(3) A, E

(4) D, E

(b) Which of the following triples of these events are independent?

(1) A, B, C

(2) A, B, D

(3) C, D, E

I can well understand the triples cases and why all of them are dependent but I am a bit confused about the pairs of events. The answer says that (A,B) and (A,D) are independent events. So I am having two troubles: 1) I can't seem to show that (A,B) are independent and 2) I seem to get that (A,E) are also independent even though I feel intuitively that it shouldn't.

Can someone help me with this ? What is the best method to approach such questions since I am just checking whether the probability of 1 event occurring is affecting the probability of the other event.

Thanks

Comment: B is related only about what happen on the second throw, and A is only related about what happen on the first throw. The throws are completely independent one of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, it's not hard to simply enumerate the entire sample space.  Here we have exactly $8$ possible events, all equally probable:

$$\{HHH,\;HHT,\;HTH,\;THH,\;HTT,\;THT,\;TTH,\;TTT\}$$

Again, each of these events has probability $\frac 18$.

Now, let's look at $A$:  half of the events start with $H$ so $P(A)=\frac 12$. Specifically the $A$-events are $$\{HHH,\;HHT,\;HTH,\;HTT\}$$

Similarly: the $B$-events are $$\{HTH,\;HTT,\;TTH,\;TTT\}$$ so, again $P(B)=\frac 12$

We note that $\{HTH,\;HTT\}$ are all the events which are simultaneously $A$ and $B$ events.

As to the conditional probabilities, we see that exactly two $A$-events are also $B$-events so $P(B|A)=\frac 12=P(B)$.  Similarly, exactly two $B$-events are also $A$-events so $P(A|B)=\frac 12=P(A)$.  As the conditional probabilities match the unconditional probabilities the events are independent.

Note:  you don't need to check both of $P(A|B)$ and $P(B|A)$.  If one of them shows independence, so will the other.  Still, when you are just starting out it's good to write everything out.

As to $A$ and $E$ we need to list the $E$ events: $$\{HTT,\;THT,\;TTH\}$$ and we see that $HTT$ is the only event which is both an $E$ and an $A$ event.  Thus $P(A|E)=\frac 13\neq P(A)$ so the events are dependent.